# How to append items to a blank array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I have a ul-li block for image listing.On clicking on an  corresponding images should delete and a value inside a `<span>`,which is sibling of image should be stored in a variable.Each time when I click,img should delete and each `<span>`'s value should be appended to jquery array variable.I did it,but when I alert the array variable it shows the single value of the current click only.ie not appending values generated through the previous click.

My JavaScript:

```
function delImg(newthis){

   var Ids= [];

   $(newthis).parent().hide();
   var Id = $(newthis).siblings('.hidden').html();
   Ids.push(Id);
   alert(Ids);
   return Ids;

}
```

The problem is `alert(Ids)` gives single variable instead of array.

Comment: Id is itself an array

Comment: @LauriElias, looks more like a string (html) to me. Shabasy: You only have one item in your array.

Comment: Use console.log instead of alerts for these and similar purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the declaration of the array *outside* of the function (so you're not resetting it every time):

```
var ids = []
function delImg(newThis){
    $(newThis).parent().hide();
    var id = $(newThis).siblings('.hidden').html();
    ids.push(id);
    return ids;
}
```

Also, naming conventions suggest that you should camelCase your variable names, so I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your array outside the function

```
var Ids = [];

function delImg(newthis){
   // ...
}
```